# Standardising a nested list of elevational values with different formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested list containing elevational data with different formatting. Some data are in meter while others are in feet.

```
elev = [
    ['800-1600 m', '2000 ft', '500 m', '1500-2200 ft', '900 m'],
    ['300-900 m', '1200 ft']
]
```

I would like to transform each list in a list of integers in such a way that intervals are split in individual values and elevations in feet are converted into meter.

```
desired_output = [
    [800, 1600, 610, 500, 460, 670, 900],
    [300, 900, 370]
]
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work and I find it difficult to read.

```
from regex import *

def ft_to_m(value):
    value = round(int(value) * 0.3048, -1)
    return(value)

map(
    lambda x: [ft_to_m(e) for e in findall(r'\d+', x)] if 'ft' in x else [int(e) for e in findall(r'\d+', x)],
    elev
)
```

How can I do it? Preferably without using a complicated list comprehension.

Comment: Are you sure you want to get rid of the intervals and convert them to their min/max values?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to get the min and max values from each list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple, straightforward solution:

```
elev = [
    ['800-1600 m', '2000 ft', '500 m', '1500-2200 ft', '900 m'],
    ['300-900 m', '1200 ft']
]

def ft_to_m(value):
    value = round(int(value) * 0.3048, -1)
    return( int(value))

def parse_elev(elev_list):
    res = []
    for item in elev_list:
        numbers = [int(n) for n in re.findall(r"\d+", item)]
        if item.endswith("ft"):
            numbers = [ft_to_m(n) for n in numbers]
        res = res + numbers
    return res

[parse_elev(l) for l in elev]
```

Result:

```
[[800, 1600, 610, 500, 460, 670, 900], [300, 900, 370]]
```